# java.util.zip.ZipException: no current ZIP entry but entry exists

Tags: java

I tried to zip a txt-file but got a ZipException. I know that i need an entry and i have it but for some reason got exception anyway. Here is piece of my code

```
public void createZip(Path source) throws Exception {
        try (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(zipFile));
             BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zipOutputStream))) {

            String entry = source.getFileName().toString();
            System.out.println(entry);
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(source.getFileName().toString()));

            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Files.newInputStream(source)))) {
                while (reader.ready()) {
                    writer.write(reader.readLine());
                }
            }

            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: no current ZIP entry
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.write(ZipOutputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:234)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:340)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:169)
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:254)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:269)
    at com.javarush.task.task31.task3110.ZipFileManager.createZip(ZipFileManager.java:31)
    at com.javarush.task.task31.task3110.Archiver.main(Archiver.java:25)
```

Comment: 1. The stack trace shows that the exception is thrown *after* `closeEntry()`. 2. You should not use `Reader` or `Writer` here. There is a pointless round-trip between `byte` and `char` that could cause errors. Just use `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. 3. `while (reader.ready())` is not a valid test for end of stream, and neither is `InputStream.available()`.

Comment: Unrelated, but the way you're reading from the `BufferedReader` is broken. First of all, `ready()` may return false even if not all data is read - possibly because the file system is busy and reading is blocked. Second, you're using `readLine()` in combination with `write`, which causes all line breaks to be removed. Since you're using both `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` you don't need to read and write using `char[]`: `String line; while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { writer.write(line); writer.newLine(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the stack trace suggested, the error is thrown when `BufferedWriter.close` is calling `ZipOutputStream.write`. This is because `BufferedWriter`, as its name suggested, is buffered. Data written by a `BufferedWriter` may not necessarily be written into the file immediately. When a `BufferedWriter` get closed (in this case closed by try-with-resources), it will flush all unwritten data, by that time your `ZipEntry` has already been closed so that's why the error.

The solution is to manually call `writer.flush()` before `zipOutputStream.closeEntry()`

```java
public void createZip(Path source) throws Exception {
    try (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(zipFile));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zipOutputStream))) {

        String entry = source.getFileName().toString();
        System.out.println(entry);
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(source.getFileName().toString()));

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Files.newInputStream(source)))) {
            while (reader.ready()) {
                writer.write(reader.readLine());
            }
        }
        writer.flush(); //Add this line!!
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```